# To get something happen

Tags: english-to-german

In English I would commonly use phrases like "I could not get the meeting postponed." I have tried translating it to "Ich konnte den Termin nicht veschoben bekommen/kriegen." but nobody (in Germany) understood what I was trying to say exactly.

Instead of completely changing structure and saying something like "Der Termin konnte leider nicht verschoben werden" or "Der Termin lässt sich nicht verschieben", how could I say this right?

What I am looking for are general suggestions, not just something that works for postponing a meeting. That was only an example :)

Comment: I think changing the structure is inevitable.

Comment: As a native speaker, I suggest: `Ich konnte keine Verschiebung des Treffens (des Termins) erreichen.`

Comment: *Ich konnte den Termin nicht verschoben bekommen.* is perfectly fine. I don't see why anyone shouldn't be able to understand the meaning of that sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"To get X Y" is a construction expressing that you cause or allow some agent or event affect X with result Y.  One German verb that can replace the meaning of "get" here is *lassen*, which can be used [similar to a modal verb](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verb-lassen/) in at least two meanings: "to allow" (in a milder way, as in "I let her take my pencil"), or to cause to do (*ich ließ ihn den Boden putzen* "I had him clean the floor").

Using this, you can say *Ich konnte den Termin nicht verschieben lassen*.  This more exactly corresponds something like "I could not let the meeting be postponed", but I think it's as close as it gets.

The reflexive *sich nicht Y lassen* is closely related to this, but just leaves out the agent part and states the possibility of Y as a fact: you didn't even try to cause Y.

Besides, while *ich habe das Meeting nicht verschoben gekriegt* might not be good formal German, it is quite understandable in a colloquial context (at least around people that know English, but I can only use introspection here).  But it's more connotated as an allowance, not so much a cause (cf. *ich habe den Vertrag nicht verlängert gekriegt*). (Ditto for *bekommen*.)

Comment: This could be a bias of growing up with English, but when I hear _ich ließ ihn den Boden putzen_, what I understand is that he was eager to clean/wash the floor and I have allowed him to, as in letting him have an opportunity.

Comment: It can really be both without context. Maybe there's a tendency to either variant, but I can't really estimate it based on pure intuition. You'd have to do some kind of corpus analysis.

Comment: I feel this misses the question.

Comment: @infinitezero In what respect? Do you think it's a bad translation of the meaning of this construction?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, *ich habe den Termin nicht verschoben bekommen* is a sentence I might have possibly used as well. Furthermore, the options you gave look fine to me. Additionally, you might also want to consider:

> - Ich habe es nicht geschafft, den Termin zu verschieben
> - Ich habe es nicht geschafft, den Termin verschieben zu lassen

There's also a very similar expression to the English one, *etwas hinbekommen*, which is a colloquial form of *etwas schaffen*, but with a focus on abilities. So

> Ich habe es nicht hinbekommen, den Termin [zu verschieben/verschieben zu lassen]

would also be possible, but suggests that it was due to lacking abilities of the speaker.